# How can I set a variable for a single Vim Ex command only?

Tags: command-line, command, nvim

I often set or modify a shell variable in Bash for the scope of a single command only:

`$ FOO=BAR <command>`

Is it possible to set or modify a variable in Vim for the scope of a single Ex command only?

Suppose I want to modify the `path` variable for a single `:find` command. I don't want to remember the old value and reset it afterwards using `:set path=`.

Comment: How about to wrap the single command in a function, and in it store the old value, set the new, run the command in question, and restore the variable? Or look into `unlet`. If this sounds OK, I could write a more detailed answer

Comment: @user907860 - If that's the proper way to do it in Vim, I guess it's OK. I'm only semi-experienced with Vim.

Comment: There are some predefined modifiers like `verbose`, `hide` and such which essentially do a very similar thing. Not applicable to user stuff though.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is nothing like that.

In my [library plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib), I've implemented a generic feature that takes care of restoring options, variables (where restoring may means `:unlet`), mappings, or trigger some other actions at the end of a sequence of operations. But it's not meant to be used on the fly. It's too verbose for that.

```
  let cleanup = lh#on#exit()
        \.restore('&l:statusline')
        \.restore('&isk')
        \.restore('b:varname')
        \.register('au! SomeAuGroup')
        \.restore_cursor()
        \.restore_buffer_mapping('<c-y>', 'i')
        .....
  try
     actions...
  finally
     call cleanup.finalize()
  endtry
```

---

Back to your concern, I guess you'd like something simple to use. We could imagine something  like `:MyExec -protect:path=tmp\ value :the old ex-command`. The problem I see is parsing the temporary value sent to `path`.  I've tried several times to have commands able to reconstruct strings and take other parameters, it's a plain headache. At best we need some unique separator. Something like `--` maybe ?

This could give

```
command! -nargs=1 ProtectExec call s:ProtectExec(<f-args>)

function! s:ProtectExec(cmdline) abort
  " Only accepts a single -override parameter
  let parts = split(a:cmdline, '\s\+--\s\+')
  if len(parts) < 2
    throw "ProtectExec: Don't forget to separate the ex-command from the overriden variable/option with '--'"
  endif
  let cleanup = lh#on#exit()
  try
    if parts[0] =~ '\v-over%[ride]:'
      let [all, var, val; dummy] = matchlist(parts[0], '\v-over%[ride]:([^=]+)\=(.*)')
      call cleanup.restore(var)
      if empty(var)
        throw "ProtectExec: Cannot extract variable name and value from `".parts[0]."`"
      endif
      " If only options and only one option would be supported,
      " then varname could be used in the the finally clause instead 
      " of the generic on#exit() object.
      let varname = lh#option#is_set_locally(var) ? '&l:'.var[1:] : var
      exe 'let '.varname.' = '.val
    endif
    exe parts[1]
  finally
    call cleanup.finalize()
  endtry
endfunction
```

That is used with:

```
:ProtectExec -override:&path='toto' -- echo "tmp:".&path
```

Note that `lh#on#exit().restore()` relies on another function: `lh#option#is_set_locally()` that I just had to fix in order to correctly recognize global-local options that haven't been locally overridden. This part has been a little tricky (we need to know how the option shall be restored: with `:set`  or `:setlocal` ).

```
let s:k_option_fullname = {
      \ 'ai': 'autoindent',
      \ 'bs': 'backspace',
      \ 'efm': 'errorformat',
      \ 'et': 'expandtab',
      \ 'ft': 'filetype',
      \ 'isk': 'iskeyword',
      \ 'rtp': 'runtimepath',
      \ 'sw': 'shiftwidth',
      \ 'ts': 'tabstop',
      \ 'tw': 'textwidth'
      \ }
function! lh#option#is_set_locally(option_name, ...) abort
  let bufid = get(a:, 1, '%')
  if a:option_name =~ '^&\(\([lg]:\)\@!.\)*$'
    " options with no explicit scope
    let options = getbufvar(bufid, '&')
    " Before 7.4.434, getbufvar() returns an empty string instead of an
    " empty dict when nothing is found
    " Also, older version of vim don't return local options with
    " getbufvar(bid, '&')
    " In global-local options case, an empty local option is an option that
    " hasn't been overriden
    let option_name = get(s:k_option_fullname, a:option_name[1:], a:option_name[1:])
    if !empty(options) && has_key(options, option_name)
      if type(options[option_name]) == type('')
        return !empty(getbufvar(bufid, '&l:'.option_name))
      else
        return getbufvar(bufid, '&l:'.a:option_name[1:]) != getbufvar(bufid, '&g:'.option_name)
      endif
    endif
  endif
  return 0
endfunction
```

IMO, unless you have many cases of commands and options you'd like to override, you'd better off with a dedicated command for searching with a temporary path -- but don't forget to check whether `'path'` is currently a local or a global option.